# VHDL output is suddenly undefined,even though compilation is passed

Tags: undefined, vhdl, simulation, modelsim

I am a student with an assignment to build and test a full adder using VHDL for use in a future assignment. It was working perfectly a few days ago, however i tried simulating again today (on a different computer) and all of my inputs and outputs are now undefined. I am using Modelsim SE-64 10.1c.

Full Adder

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity FullAdder is

  port (A, B, Cin : in std_logic;
        Cout, sum : out std_logic);

end FullAdder;

architecture V1 of FullAdder is
  begin

    Cout <= ((B and Cin) or (A and Cin) or (A and B));
    sum  <= ((A and (not(B)) and (not Cin)) or ((not A) and (not B) and Cin) or (A and B and Cin) or ((not A) and B and (not Cin)));

end V1;
```

Testbench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity FullAdderTB is
end;

architecture TB1 of FullAdderTB is
  component FullAdder
    port (A, B, Cin : in std_logic;
          Cout, sum : out std_logic);

 end component;

  signal A, B, Cin, Cout, sum : std_logic;

begin

  stimuli: process
  begin
    A <= '0'; B <= '0'; Cin <= '0'; wait for 10 NS;
    A <= '0'; B <= '0'; Cin <= '1'; wait for 10 NS;
    A <= '0'; B <= '1'; Cin <= '0'; wait for 10 NS;
    A <= '0'; B <= '1'; Cin <= '1'; wait for 10 NS;
    A <= '1'; B <= '0'; Cin <= '0'; wait for 10 NS;
    A <= '1'; B <= '0'; Cin <= '1'; wait for 10 NS;
    A <= '1'; B <= '1'; Cin <= '0'; wait for 10 NS;
    A <= '1'; B <= '1'; Cin <= '1'; wait for 10 NS;
    wait;
 end process;

 G1: FullAdder port map (A=>A, B=>B, Cin=>Cin, Cout=>Cout, sum=>sum);

end;
```

Comment: Are you sure your simulation is set up correctly? At first glance, I don't see any reason your code shouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't changed any settings at all to do with the simulation.

Comment: If all ports are undefined maybe you didn't compile the testbench.The name of ports in both modules are the same and it's possible the waves in Modelsim is related to `FullAdder` not `FullAdderTB`.

Comment: My thoughts as well - make sure all components are compiled, and that your sim is targeting the correct object. Make sure there are no errors/warnings when loading the sim. Your code itself does not appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. I don't see any reason your code shouldn't work. I think your problem is in modelsim:

1. Create a new Model Sim project.
2. Add you VHDL files then compile all
3. Go to the simulate menu and choose start simulation.
4. Go to the view menu and choose object and waveform
5. Drag and drop your inputs and outputs and press the run button after changing the clock period for each input and output.

Good luck